# python socket can not send data after receiving a large data

Tags: python, sockets

I have a simple python script as a socket server.

I use this script to connect a java server and send/recv data in protobuffer format.

```
# socket_client.py

client_socket = None
ADDRESS = "x.x.x.x"
PORT = xxxx

def connect(address, port):
    global client_socket
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((address, port))
    client_socket.setblocking(True)
```

And when a use press a key the script will call request method to send a message to the server and then wait for the result and then return the result to the user:

```
def recv_timeout(the_socket, pack_len, timeout = 8):
    to_read = pack_len
    total_data = []; data = ''; begin = time.time()
    while 1:
        if total_data and time.time() - begin > timeout:
            break
        elif time.time() - begin > timeout * 2:
            break
        try:
            data = the_socket.recv(pack_len)
            if data:
                to_read -= len(data)
                total_data.append(data)
                begin = time.time()
                if to_read <= 0:
                    break
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except:
            pass
    return ''.join(total_data)

def request(message):
    global client_socket

    # ......
    send_data = data_util.makeSendData(message)

    # send
    send_len = client_socket.send(send_data)
    print 'send_len: %d' % send_len

    # recv head for total length of the result
    pack_len = client_socket.recv(4)
    pack_len = struct.unpack('!i', pack_len)[0]
    print 'pack_len: %d' % pack_len

    # recv all
    recv_data = recv_timeout(client_socket, pack_len)

    # ......

    return recv_data
```

This works fine when I try to send a heart beat message to server and I can recv data from the server and decode the message successfully.

The output of the log:

```
send_len: 31
pack_len: 27
```

And then I tried to send a message (login command) and the server will return a large amount of data to me:

```
send_len: 52
pack_len: 3494
```

The first time when I send this command, it works fine, the server can receive my message in length 52 and I can receive all the data from the server in length 3494 and I can decode the pack successfully.

But, the problem is after receiving the data of the login command with a large amount of return data, I can not send any command anymore.

Say, I try to send a heart beat command again after the login command, the log output is :

```
send_len: 31
```

The line

```
client_socket.send(send_data)
```

is called and it returns the result same as before which seems to be ok. But the server shows no incoming command at all and for the script , it is blocked at the line forerver :

```
pack_len = client_socket.recv(4)
```

I think the problem is at the python script side not the server side but just can not figure out what it is. Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: My first thought was something getting caught in a buffer. Idk if that even makes sense here. I'm tired. Try flushing and see if that solves anything.

Comment: I also think there is something wrong in the buffer but I just do not know how to do the flushing here (I tried to do some research)... Can you give me some advice ?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've written Python. The socket objects, or their underlying streams, should have a `flush` method. Try flushing after sending on the sending end.

Comment: When you sent the big chunk, it may have increased the size of the buffer. If the buffer is waiting to be a certain percent full before flushing itself, the message may be getting caught in there.

Comment: I tried but it seems that there is no flush method or similar one here... The chunk I am sending is very small (length of 30)... The most weird thing to me is that why the server can not receive my message after the send method is called (and the returned length is right)

Comment: You wrote _I think the problem is at the python script side not the server side_, but you have shown no evidence for this assumption.